# Android activity Background affects alertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a style I created like this:

```
<style name="myStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000099</item>
</style>
```

Then I created an xml and an activity, and in the manifest declared this

```
                     <activity android:name=".Try" 
            android:theme="@style/myStyle" >
    </activity>
```

Then when I start this activity I have an xml with a background color (blue);
THe problem is , when I create an Alert Dialog

```
     AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder....
```

It is also affected by this background (It looks more like a blue rectangle behind it that is bigger then the dialog and is coming out from all 4 sides).
I dont want it to be, I want to use another style for the alert dialog.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the background of your activity is too prominent when the dialog pops up? If so, you can blur what's in the background with the following code:

```
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

Or are you saying that the background of your activity is being applied to the background of your dialog...?

Comment: here is a pic of that: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/718/colorbx.png/ Dont be confused by the yellow color, this is the style i want the dialog to have. THe problem is the green color from the calling activity is destroying it

Comment: for you question, it is not a blur i need. The background of the activity is being applied to the dialog.

Comment: Have u set theme so all window bg are same?

Comment: and what theme are you using for the dialog?

Comment: its something i built that extends alerDialog. it does not really metter, even if i dont set a theme to the alertDialog i get the same green thing around it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix that, well not entirley but to pass around it.
Instead of using:
 #000099 
I used
 IMAGE_NAME 
and I added a green rectangle image at the "drawable" folder.
This makes the background to become from an image instead of painting it, and the image does not affect the Dailog.
It will look a bit different (for example it will cover the white border as well) but it is better then before.